# has_many through and additional data : count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle a field storing the quantity of the same object in my join table.

[image: Schema]

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :connections
   has_many :connector_types, :through => :connections
end

class ConnectorType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :elements, :through => :connections
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element
  belongs_to :connector_type
end
```

When I add a `ConnectorType` to an `Element` :

- A `Connection` must be created if there isn't for this `ConnectorType`
- If a `Connection` for this `ConnectorType` exists, `Connection#number` should be increment

When I remove a `ConnectorType` from an `Element` :

- `Connection#number` should be decrement.
- If `Connection#number == 0` delete the `Connection`

I am new to rails I don't know the Rails way to do this :

- Callback
- Dump the number field and store as duplicate rows in the join model.
- ...

Comment: What do you want your callback to do? You have tons of options for that http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html Have you looked into has_and_belongs_to_many for a join association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to monitor the number of connections between a given element and a given connector_type, but you do not want to have duplicate Connection objects in your database?

You can use callbacks for this (code not tested)

```
# connection.rb 
before_create  :bc_callback
before_destroy :bd_callback


private
def before_create
  if (existing_connection = self.find_by_element_id_and_connector_type_id(element_id, connector_type_id))
    existing_connection.number++
    existing_connection.save
    return false # Do not create a new connection object
  end
end

def before_destroy
  number--
  # If you still have 1 connection or more, the object won't be destroyed
  if (number > 0)
    save
    return false
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure that adding a connector_type to an element via the has_many relation like this:

```
@element.connector_types << @connector_type
```

will trigger the creation of a new connection, if there already is one linking this element and this connector type...

Comment: That's what I want, but when I return false in my before_create callback to avoid the object creation have got a ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved

Comment: Isn't this because you are calling create! instead of create, or save! instead of save?